# Theme options not being sent to Database

Tags: database, options, posting

Currently working on a little project for a theme, doing this so i can learn the in's and out's of wordpress.

So far i've got to the point of adding sections, and fields within those sections. However now that they're all displaying in the correct tab + section, nothing is being to the database, however i get keeping the "options updated" message appear, and yet nothing is saved on the options page nor are the settings in the database (wp_options - i assume)

if you need any other parts of code let me know :).

Thanks In advance

here is the form which posts to the database:

```
function semantic_virgin_admin_options_page() { ?>
    <div class ="wrap">
        <?php semantic_virgin_get_settings_page_tabs(); ?>  <!-- adding in our Page tabs-->
        <?php if ( isset( $_GET['settings-updated'] ) ) :  ?>
            <div class='updated'><p><?php _e( 'Theme settings updated successfully.', 'semantic virgin' ); ?></p></div> <!-- Check to see whether to update has gone through-->
        <?php endif; ?>

        <form action="options.php" method="post">
            <?php
            settings_fields('theme_semantic_virgin_options');
            do_settings_sections('semantic-virgin-theme-options');
            ?>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>

            <?php $tab = ( isset( $_GET['tab'] ) ? $_GET['tab'] : 'general' ); ?>
            <input name="theme_semantic_virgin_options[submit-<?php echo $tab; ?>]" type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e('Save Settings', 'semantic virgin'); ?>" />
            <input name="theme_semantic_virgin_options[reset-<?php echo $tab; ?>]" type="submit" class="button-secondary" value="<?php _e('Reset Defaults', 'semantic virgin'); ?>" />
                <script>
                    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                        $('.wp-color-picker-field').wpColorPicker();
                    });
                </script> 
            <!-- HTML MARK UP GOES HERE-->
        </form>
    </div>
<?php 
}
```

Comment: obviously your problem is in the way you where adding sections and fields. From the code snippet that you posted it is impossible to guess what you have done wrong

Comment: Hey, i've finally figured out what i had done. You were correct in saying about the fields. i Simply wasn't echoing the values from the Database, back into the fields.